# Is there any way I can use 'nmap' port scanner, to generate and output result on my Django App

Tags: python, django, linux, nmap

I'm trying to create some network app in Django, and what I would like to ask: Is it possible to do something like this: Client type IP address, than server scans it with 'nmap', after that the result passed to the Django app, and than I do whole bunch of stuff with it.

Just want to know is it possible to make it, or it sounds ridiculous?

Comment: Sure, google "bash command from python" or the like. `subprocess.Popen(['nmap', ip])`. I'm just not very familiar with it's problems / gotchas; so I won't write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be something along the lines of:

```
pout,perr = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', '192.168.1.2', '-oX', '-'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

xml_results = pout.read()
```

There are a couple nmapXML -> Python dict scripts floating around as well if you google a bit.

There's somewhat of a problem with this approach - lets call it the naive approach because it doesn't scale very well, or deal with things like the machine not pinging and nmap falling back to slow-scan (which can take literally hours depending on the target network)

Consider making a server that runs nmap asyncronously and can provide status back to the user - as well as the ability to cancel a scan in progress.

Comment: For prior art, see [Rainmap](http://nmap.org/rainmap/), a project by a Google Summer of Code intern working for the Nmap project. If you want to browse the source, see Alexandru's [Github page](https://github.com/xorbyte/rainmap) for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Nmap has a python library (or a wrapper?) called python-nmap at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap.

You can install it using

`pip install python-nmap`

You can use a library like `celery` to use it in Django